# Python code returning syntax error on "if self.hp < 0" line

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I've been following along with [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J25SnoX97-0) series of youtube videos in order to get a more hands on approach to python. I don't have a deep understanding of what some of the code does, but I more or less get what each piece is supposed to achieve, even though I may not be sure how.

I'm getting a Syntax error on the last line here:

```
class Character(object):
def __init__(self, name, hp):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = hp 

    self.dead = False
def attack(self, other):
    pass

def update(self):
    if self.hp < 0     #Error's on this line
        self.dead = True
        self.hp = 0
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "game.py", line 4, in
<module>
    from Characters.player import *   File "/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/rpg/Characters/player.py", line 2,
in <module>
    from character import *   File "/Users/Devlin/Desktop/Dev/Python/rpg/Characters/character.py", line
12
    if self.hp < 0
                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: add a `:`, `if self.hp < 0 :`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a colon (`:`) at the end of the line:

```
if hp < 0:
```

Comment: Huh. Don't I feel silly. Thanks for your help, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `init` also *looks* like a constructor. As such, it should likely be `__init__` instead of `init`. Otherwise, you're going to run into problems with it not being executed at object instantiation.

Comment: For the moment I'm just following along with that tutorial exactly. I tried what you suggested and it returned a TypeError (`TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`). Would I need to go back into other parts of the code and adjust things accordingly?